# SignalR + Kubernetes + APIM

Tags: c#, .net, azure, signalr, azure-api-management

I'm trying to use signalR but having trouble connecting to the hub from my client.

I have a set of microservices located in a kubernetes cluster, where one of the services is exposed through Api Management in azure. How can i from my SEPEARATE client app connect to the hub i have create in my exposed microservice?

this is my client code:

```
 this._hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithAutomaticReconnect()
             .WithUrl("??????????????/notishub")
             .Build();
```

And this is what i have in my server microservice:

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
 {
     endpoints.MapHub<NotificationHub>("/notishub");
 });
```

And ofcourse it works locally if just type in localhost:5000/notishub but when deployed im not sure how i can reach it through Apim? And its not an option to make the cluster nodes IP adress public.
Alternativly if anyone has an other idea on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You AKS needs an Ingress Controller. Your APIM will point to the cluster ingress controller.